# Example of function with a certain behavior.

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, examples, counterexamples

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$. Consider the following properties:

$(1)$ - There are positive constants $a$ and $r$ such that $\forall x, y$
$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq a(1 + |x|^r+|y|^r)|x-y|.$$

$(2)$ - There is a positive constants $b$ such that $\forall x, y$
$$(f(x)-f(y))(x-y)\leq b(x-y)^2.$$

$(3)$ - $f(0)=0$, (or $f(0)$ is limited).

$(4)$ - There is a positive constant $c$ such that 
$$f(x)x \leq c(1 + x^2).$$

The questions are:

$(1) + (3) + (4) \Rightarrow (2)$ ????

or

There is $f$ that satisfies  $(1) + (3) + (4)$ but, not satisfies $(2)$????

REMARK: Is easy to see that $(1) + (2) + (3)$ implies $(4)$, or only, $(2) + (3)$ implies $(4)$.

Comment: For $(1)$, When $x < y$, the right hand side is certainly negative, but the left hand side is non negative. Is there a typo?

Comment: (1) can only hold for $a=0$ and $f$ constant. Did you mean to have $|x-y|$ on the right-hand side? Are there any other absolute values missing in (2) or (4)? And what does “$f(0)$ is limited” mean?

Comment: Thanks, i had forgotten, in (1) is |x-y| and not (x-y).

Comment: As given, `$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^{42}(1+\sin x),&x<0,\\0,&x\ge0\end{cases}$` is a counterexample. Are you *really* sure you don’t want absolute values on the left-hand side of (4)?

Comment: I don't find it easy to see that $(1)+(2)+(3)$ implies $(4)$ considering $f(x)=-x^3$ appears to be a counterexample.  I think Emil is right and you want absolute values in $(2)$ and $(4)$.

Comment: @Aubrey: (2) + (3) implies (4) by taking $y=0$ in (2).

Comment: Dear Emil,

If I understand correctly, you gave an example that:

$(1) + (3) + (4)$ does not imply $(2)$ right?

Comment: Aubrey, again Emil is correct.

Comment: @Anderson: Yes, that’s what the example does. However, it exploits the fact that (4) does not require anything about the behaviour of $f(x)$ for negative $x$ as long as $f$ is nonnegative, which made me wonder whether that’s the intended meaning of the condition: the context suggests that you are considering properties which somehow restrict the growth rate of the function; the current (4) does not do that, one would expect the condition to read $|f(x)x|\le c(1+x^2)$ (and then the example no longer works).

Comment: @Emil: Your example is correct with regard to the condition $f(x)x\leq c(1 + x^2) $, that's right for the problem which i intend to apply the example you gave. What matters is growth on top.

If you intend to use your example I referred to you as the author of it, if you do not mind.
